How to specify the position of Arrowhead in Graph's EdgeShapeFunction?
I have a graph defined as follows:
Graph[
   ...,
   EdgeShapeFunction->{(_\[DirectedEdge]_)->{"FilledArrow","ArrowSize"->0.02}}
]

I can't find the option to specify ArrowPosition. I tried the following but it didn't work:
Graph[
   ...,
   EdgeShapeFunction->{(_\[DirectedEdge]_)->{"FilledArrow","ArrowSize"->0.02,"ArrowPosition"->0.5}}
]

I tried querying the ResourceData but I can't see how to find the options:
ResourceData["EdgeShapeFunction","FilledArrow"]

The documentation of this is so bad.

"Options[Graph]" shows you all options of Graph. There is no option "ArrowPosition".

We can access the options for built-in EdgeShapeFunctions using the function GraphComputation`GraphElementData:
GraphComputation`GraphElementData["FilledArrow", "Options"]


{"ArrowSize" -> Automatic, "ArrowPositions" -> Automatic}


Use GraphElementData[{"FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> yourArrowSizeChoice, "ArrowPositions" -> yourPositionChoice}] as the option setting for EdgeShapeFunction:
CycleGraph[10, 
 DirectedEdges -> True, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> 
  GraphElementData[{"FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.05, "ArrowPositions" -> .7}]]


Row[CycleGraph[10, DirectedEdges -> True, ImageSize -> 300, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style["ArrowPositions" -> #, 16, ShowStringCharacters -> True], 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> 
     GraphElementData[{"FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.075, 
       "ArrowPositions" -> #}]] & /@ {.3, .5, .8}, 
  Spacer[10] ]



or ResourceFunction["GraphElementData"]["FilledArrow", "Options"]

RandomGraph[{10, 30},
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[{{.04, .4}}]]


